# Basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

One can prove that a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3})$ is the set $\{1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{6} \}$.  This got me wondering if the following is true:

> Let $\alpha, \beta$ be elements that are (1) not rational and (2) not scalar multiples of each other (where the scalars come from $\mathbb{Q}$).  Then is $\{1, \alpha, \beta, \alpha\beta\}$ a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha, \beta)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

(Note: I said $\alpha, \beta$ are *not rational* instead of *irrational* since I am not assuming $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.)

If this is true, can you provide a proof?  And if not, perhaps give a counterexample?

Comment: Consider $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: No: $\mathbf Q(\pi,\sqrt 2)$  is not even finite-dimensional.

Comment: @Bernard  This is a good one, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Compiled from the comments and posted as CW in order to mark the question as answered*.)

The proposition does not hold true in general. Counterexamples:

- finite extension: $\;\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{2})$
- infinite extension: $\;\mathbb{Q}(\pi, \sqrt{2})$